# Material UI SelectField component falls out of sync with state (using React/Redux)

Tags: javascript, forms, reactjs, redux, material-ui

I have component `LayoutSelector` with a drop down form that updates state.plate.layout. The state is passed to the component as a prop. On my machine, the selected menu item stays in sync with my state after state changes-when the user selects a new Layout, the form shows the layout:

[image]

However, in production, when you select a layout, other changes in the view reflect the new state but the menu shows the layout that was there initially. If you click to another step and come back, the layout form will show the current (correct) layout.

Furthermore, Redux DevTools show me that the state is changed correctly.

I am passing the layout selector the props as follows:

```
value={this.props.layout}
```

Here is my component:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import SelectField from 'material-ui/SelectField';
import MenuItem from 'material-ui/MenuItem';
import Paper from 'material-ui/Paper';
import { Grid, Row } from 'react-inline-grid';

class LayoutSelector extends Component {

    render() {
        const handleChange = (event, index, value) => this.props.handleLayoutChange(value);
        const style = {
            height: 130,
            width: 650,
            margin: 10,
            textAlign: 'left',
            display: 'inline-block'
        };
        return (
            <div style={{ marginLeft: '20px', topPadding: '0px', topMargin: '0px' }}>
                <Paper zDepth={1} style={style}>
                    <Grid>
                        <Row>
                            <SelectField
                                floatingLabelText="Layout"
                                value={this.props.layout}
                                onChange={handleChange}
                                style={{ marginLeft: '20px', topPadding: '0px', topMargin: '0px' }}
                            >
                                <MenuItem value={'listorder'} primaryText="List Order" />
                                <MenuItem value={'roundrobin'} primaryText="Round Robin" />
                                <MenuItem value={'random'} primaryText="Random" />
                                <MenuItem value={'spreadsample'} primaryText="Spread Sample" />
                            </SelectField>
                            <p style={{ marginLeft: '10px', verticalAlign: 'middle', topMargin: '30px' }}><i>{this.props.description}</i> </p>
                        </Row>
                    </Grid>
                </Paper>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

LayoutSelector.propTypes = {
    layout: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
    handleLayoutChange: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    description: PropTypes.string
};

LayoutSelector.defaultProps = {
    description: ''
};

export default LayoutSelector;
```

And here's the container:

```
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { changeLayout, showLayer, showSample, postNotification, clearUserChanges } from '../actions';
import LayoutSelector from '../components/Stepper/Steps/LayoutSelector';
import { getAttributes } from '../selectors/samples';
import { getDescription } from '../selectors/layout';

function handleLayoutChange(value, dispatch) {
    dispatch(changeLayout(value));
    dispatch(clearUserChanges());
    dispatch(postNotification(`New layout chosen: ${value}`));
}

function handleSampleVisChange(e, dispatch) {
    dispatch(showSample(e.target.checked));
}

function handleAttrVisChange(e, dispatch) {
    dispatch(showLayer(e.target.value, e.target.checked));
}

const mapStateToProps = (state, ownProps) => ({
    attributes: getAttributes(state),
    showSample: state.plate.showSample,
    layout: state.plate.layout,
    visibleAttribute: state.plate.visibleAttribute,
    description: getDescription(state)
});

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch, ownProps) => ({
    handleLayoutChange: (values) => {
        handleLayoutChange(values, dispatch);
    },
    handleSampleVisChange: (values) => {
        handleSampleVisChange(values, dispatch);
    },
    handleAttrVisChange: (values) => {
        handleAttrVisChange(values, dispatch);
    }
});

const LayoutForm = connect(
    mapStateToProps,
    mapDispatchToProps
)(LayoutSelector);

export default LayoutForm;
```

I'm mostly puzzled about why this could be working perfectly in dev but not production. It's the only difference I've noticed. My package.json:

```
{
  "name": "client",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "material-ui": "^0.18.3",
    "ndarray": "^1.0.18",
    "prop-types": "^15.5.10",
    "react": "^15.6.1",
    "react-cellblock": "^3.0.0",
    "react-dom": "^15.6.1",
    "react-flexbox-grid": "^1.1.3",
    "react-inline-grid": "^0.5.3",
    "react-redux": "^5.0.5",
    "react-router": "^3.0.5",
    "react-tap-event-plugin": "^2.0.1",
    "redux-devtools-extension": "^2.13.2",
    "redux-form": "^6.8.0",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.2.0",
    "reselect": "^3.0.1",
    "react-scripts": "^0.8.5",
    "underscore": "^1.8.3",
    "redux": "^3.7.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-eslint": "^7.2.3",
    "babel-loader": "^7.0.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "eslint": "^3.19.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "^15.0.1",
    "eslint-config-react-app": "^0.6.2",
    "eslint-plugin-flowtype": "^2.32.1",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.3.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^5.0.3",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.0.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "jest",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "test:watch": "npm test -- --watch"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two things which can affect your production compared to dev environment:

1. If you are using web pack probably your production configuration is different than the one you use to bundle in dev environment. This production configuration can really cause side effects. 
   since you created the app with [create-react-app](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app) that uses react scripts that use webpack behind the scenes and enable you to customize it.
2. make sure you are installing the same packages in dev and in production or event better you can use npm shrinkwrap to freeze dependencies
3. You can see how to customize webpack configuration without [ejecting](https://daveceddia.com/customize-create-react-app-webpack-without-ejecting/). The issue here that once you create your app with create-react-app script you "inherited" tons of configuration which might also cause errors (and maybe need to be configured differently).

Answer (score 2):

You said you have the bug only in production build, while your local build works ok.

I don't see any significant altering of behavior based on environment in [material-ui source-code](https://github.com/callemall/material-ui/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=NODE_ENV&type=).

So my suggestion is to make sure your have the same version of `material-ui` both in your local `node_modules` and on build machine (in case you have any).

Comment: Thanks! I tried looking at package.json for differences between my dev and prod dependencies. It seems like the versions of material-ui are the same. I added my package.json to my question above.

Answer (score 1):

Please check versions of the packages. You could have installed different version of React in your dev server and different in prod server.

You have used prop types, which is depreciated in the latest version of React.

Comment: This is considered as a comment instead of answer.

Comment: I've compared the versions on prod and dev, and don't see any differences. Also, I'm importing PropTypes from 'prop-types' which I think is still acceptable: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/typechecking-with-proptypes.html. Thanks!